# Route template conflict with Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have 2 GET endpoints implemented via Azure Functions

- `/products/{productId}` : Gets me the product by id
- `/products/status` : Get certain 'status' of the products collection.

Doing GET calls always ends up in the 'Get by id' function.

How do I make these 2 explicit endpoints and not treat 'status' as an id value? I was under the impression that if a route matches the uri then it takes precedence.

Is related to this issue - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/11755

Cannot use Route constraints for Guid ids.

`/products/{productId:guid}` disambiguates the function calls but fails to bind the value to the parameter.

Comment: Can you provide the version of Azure Functions that you're using?

Comment: Could you please share the whole Function method signature for both API calls?

Comment: route constraints should work for `:guid` provided the value passed is a valid Guid. but cant say for sure as no [mcve] was provided

Comment: It's V1 (.NET Framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> fails to bind the value to the parameter

It's an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2279) tracked but not solved yet.

> [Route Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints) allow specifying datatypes for query string parameters on HttpTrigger route property. These constraints are only used to match the route.
>   When using binding parameters datatype is converted to strings.

So if you use `Guid productId` to accept the input parameter, you will meet the error `Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Guid'`.

Workaround is to accept the guid as string, you can use `Guid.Parse(productId)` if you need a Guid Object.

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(..., Route = "product/{productId:guid}")]HttpRequestMessage req, string productId)
```